# Jest integration with Adonis V5

Tags: node.js, typescript, testing, jestjs, adonis.js

I'm developing an application with Adonis v5 but its test runner isn't finished. So, my workaround is to apply Jest in its place. I got this working but I'm having trouble importing types from Adonis.

In any model, I have the following import:

```
import { BaseModel, column } from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm'
```

To solve the alias, I added this rule in `jest.config.js`:

```js
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^App(.*)$': '<rootDir>/app$1',
  '^@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Database$': '@adonisjs/lucid/build/src/Database/index.js',
  '^@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm$': '@adonisjs/lucid/build/adonis-typings/orm.d.ts',
  //'^@ioc:Adonis/Core/Validator$': '',
},
```

The third rule points to the previous import. Inside of the pointed file, I found the declaration of a module which exports the desired types.

```
declare module '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm' {
    import { ScopeFn, LucidModel, HooksDecorator, ...
    ...
```

The complete file is [this](https://github.com/adonisjs/lucid/blob/develop/adonis-typings/orm.ts).

When I run Jest, I get this error. What am I missing? Before I forget, I'm using `ts-jest` to define the settings of Jest.

[image]

Comment: managed to solve?

Comment: Have you got `esModuleInterop` set to true in tsconfig?

Comment: I don't remember about esModuleInterop. My settings are the same of default. My unique solution is to use Cypress Test Framework disabling all resources to tests beyond the back-end.

Comment: Despite the excessive resources, Cypress is extremely easy and usefull